# soldermask top for non plated holes

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, solder-mask

I am here to clarify doubt on soldermask for non plated holes. I know soldermask is used to protect board from oxidation and prevention of solder bridges and accurate placement of components to be soldered.

But in non plated holes I think it it is not necessary.

1. is it important of given soldermask to non plated holes or not?
2. Why so?

Comment: Do your non-plated holes have pad rings around them on the top and bottom sides?

Comment: may i know about pad rings?

Answer (score 1):

For unplated holes it is better to pull back the solder mask by about 5-10 mils (assuming no pads) around the hole.

If there are pads (for example, for a mounting hole) you should pull back the solder mask enough to completely clear the screw head.